# SQL joining tables based on IDs

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables;

A title table that has columns `Title_ID` and `Title_Name`.

A team table that has columns `Team_ID` and `Team_Name`

A link table that has columns `Title_ID` and `Team_ID`

I basically want to merge the first two tables using the third one (using the `ID` fields), Since I want to create a table where I have both Title_Name and Team_Name matched up accordingly to the link table. Is there an SQL statement that could do this? Been trying to look at left and right joins but can't think of how to merge properly.

Comment: Even if it's irrelevant in terms of `JOIN` - is it `MySQL` or `MS SQL Server`?

Comment: Do you have one-to-one relation between Title_ID & Team_ID or one-to-many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ti.title_name, te.team_name
from link l
inner join title ti on l.title_id = ti.title_id
inner join team te on l.team_id = te.team_id
```

Answer (score 1):

**Merge the first two tables(TITLE, TEAM) using the third one(LINK)**

```
SELECT * FROM link l
INNER JOIN title t1 ON t1.title_id = l.title_id
INNER JOIN team t2 ON t2.team_id = l.team_id;
```